# Why does Array.from(FileList) lose all meta data

Tags: javascript, arrays, filelist

Using a html input file element, I captured the filelist using:

```
 let fileSelected = e.target.files;
```

Since this is a multiple input element, fileSelected is a nodelist.

I would like to convert it to aa array but when I do it, I loose all the metadata such as name, size, lastmodified, etc.

```
listArray = Array.from(fileSelected);
```

The problem I am facing is when I `console.log(listArray)` I only see the array with the element : File

I would like one array which has both the File and the Metadata.

My guess is that it is not possible because File blobs are not allowed to be in arrays because they are immutable?

Right now I am managing with 2 different arrays, one for the file blobs and another for the file metadata. This resulting in difficulty in updating/inserting more files and maintain both arrays in sycn.

Is their a method to covert a Filelist in to a array that also keeps the metadata in the same array.

Thank you.
Rishi

Comment: Are you able to provide a code sample to illustrate this? When I do `Array.from` on a `FileInput.files` I still get the metadata

Comment: `Array.from` doesn't change the list elements. Probably you don't click on the logged array and assume you lose the properties.

Comment: Please show us how you were accessing the metadata directly on the files list, and how you are trying to access the metadata in your array (which doesn't work).